# Is a graph with degree sequence 2,2,2 complete or cycle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is a graph with degree sequence 2,2,2 complete or cycle??

Answer (score 2):

It is both. $K_3 = C_3$. Above $n=3$ this will fail of course. $K_n$ has degree sequence $n-1,n-1,\ldots,n-1$ while $C_n$ has $2,2,\ldots,2$. Here we happen to have $2 = n-1$

Comment: only one of them should be selected....

Comment: If it really is 3 long (not longer), pick any one. A cycle will always be correct and is probably intended.

Comment: @pavan If this is from a multiple choice test where you're only allowed to choose one optioin, then it is not a very good test.